# Problema com taglig em Java

Tags: java, java-ee, jsp, jstl

Estou construindo uma págna `JSP`, porém, estou com um problema para referenciar minha `taglib` da `jstl`. Estou a referenciando da seguinte maneira:

```
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
```

Mas no `Eclipse` estou recebendo a seguinte mensagem de erro:

> Can not find the tag library descriptor for
>   "http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"

Segue abaixo o código da minha página `JSP`:

```
<%@page contentType="text/html"%>
<%@page pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html>
    <head>
        <title>Mostrando contatos</title>
    </head>
    <body>

        <table border="1" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0">
            <tr>
                <th>ID - Atualizar</th>
                <th>Nome</th>
                <th>E-mail</th>
                 <th>Excluir </th>
            </tr>

        <c:forEach var="lista" items="${ requestScope.contatosList }">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <a href="FrontController?action=SelecionarContato&id=${lista.codigo}">
                        ${lista.codigo}
                </a>
                                    </td>
                <td>${lista.nome}</td>
                <td>${lista.email}</td>

                <td>
                    <a href="FrontController?action=DeletarContato&id=${lista.codigo}">
                        Excluir
                    </a>
                </td>
            </tr>

        </c:forEach>
        </table>
                <br />
        <a href="formGravarContato.jsp">Adicionar um novo Autor</a>
        <br />
        <a href="index.jsp">Página Principal</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

Segue abaixo uma imagem do erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguém poderia me ajudar a resolver esse problema?

Comment: Tente adicionar o .jar da implementação do JSTL à sua pasta lib.
Download aqui: http://search.maven.org/#browse|-1002239620
Baixe o arquivo: javax.servlet.jsp.jstl-1.2.1.jar

Caso não seja esta a resolução, tente o seguinte:
Botão direito no projeto, properties -> targeted runtimes, e então selecione o servidor que está utilizando.

No SO en-US, também há uma postagem similar, com várias sugestões de respostas Segue link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5987908/how-to-resolve-can-not-find-the-tag-library-descriptor-for-http-java-sun-co

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Faça donwload desses dois jars e copie para dentro da pasta /WebContent/WEB-INF/lib

[javax.servlet.jsp.jstl](http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=javax/servlet/jsp/jstl/javax.servlet.jsp.jstl-api/1.2.1/javax.servlet.jsp.jstl-api-1.2.1.jar)

[javax.servlet.jsp.jstl-api](http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=javax/servlet/jsp/jstl/javax.servlet.jsp.jstl-api/1.2.1/javax.servlet.jsp.jstl-api-1.2.1.jar)

O diretório deve ficar assim: 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]